# Indexing is not working

Tags: woocommerce, algolia

Just wondering if someone can help.

I have setup alogolia plugin in wordpress and try to index the content. However, only some data is indexed and I keep getting an error on the indexing page in woocommerce.

I get the following error:

> wp_remote_post() failed, indexing won't work. Checkout the logs for more details.

URL called: https://www.latestbuy.com.au/wp-admin/admin-post.php

Also, when I try to search on the site, I get the following error in the console

> POST https://02ywvd0g5t-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/wp_terms_product_cat/query?x-a…plication-id=02YWVD0G5T&x-algolia-api-key=9bf593cf7f7dd2a8388ab640dd14a924 404 (Not Found)
>
> Uncaught Error: Index wp_terms_product_cat does not exist(…)

I have tried this on two different servers and two different hosts and get the same issue.

Any one experienced this?

Thanks.

Vish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin does need your WordPress instance to be able to reach itself over http or https protocol.

This is required so that we avoid reaching max memory limit or max execution time limit.

In your case you are using SSL.

If your ssl certificate is not valid or can not be handled by your openssl library AND your website is also available over http, you can add the following line to your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'ALGOLIA_LOOPBACK_HTTP', true );
```

This will force the loopback calls to happen over http instead of https.

If that doesn't solve your issue, please post the log details of wp_remote_post error available on the 'Logs' page as a comment.